# Rails_admin & view image at list action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

```
Ruby 1.9.3  
Rail 3.2.9  
rails_admin 0.4.5
```

All my images are stored on disk.
I would like to show their thumbnails on list action.
How can i do that?

There is no a field for storing images in a database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you images are stored on a disk, I assume that each record stores the path to the image, correct?

There's is no way to do this out-of-the-box. The easiest (and it's not particularly easy) solution is to modify the index/list action that comes with rails_admin. [Here's where you should start](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/index.rb) You will either need to extend this action or create a new one.